# How to display a js variable value in HTML,<div id> with mouseover effect

Tags: javascript, html, css

In javascript I have a variable which contains some value which i get from JSON.

```
var a =recipe[0].step[1].processingTime;//here processing time is stored in var a
```

I want to display this value by showing a description box, when I hover my mouse over a small `div id` in HTML.

```
<tr>
    <td>Recipe 0</td>
    <td>
        <div id="p1"><div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

How to do that? Can anyone please show me a easy solution.

Comment: do you want to know, how to create  a tooltip?

Comment: Which element should the mouse hover to display the description box?

Comment: it will display a processing time, which is a number.

Comment: You realize that when `<div id="p1"></div>` is empty, it will have a size of 0px x 0px and the mouse won't be able to hover over it.

Comment: well this div is created under a table.and the table cantain 40 more div. and each id of  div has height:20px;padding-top:5px;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a vanilla javascript version:

```js
var a = "something to show";

function showProcTime(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener("mouseout", clearProcTime);
  elem.innerHTML = '<div class="popupBox">' + a + '</div>';
  elem.style.backgroundColor = "#EFEFEF";
}

function clearProcTime(e) {
  var elem = e.target;
  elem.removeEventListener("mouseout", clearProcTime);
  elem.innerHTML = "";
  elem.style.backgroundColor = "#CCCCCC";
}
```

```css
.popupBox {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  background-color: #EFEFEF;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="p1" style="background-color:#CCCCCC;display:inline-block;width:200px;height:20px;" onMouseOver='showProcTime(this)'>roll over me
  <div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the simple native html tooltip you can just set the elements `title` atrribute. For example the ones that get shown when you hover over the SO voting arrows

```
document.getElementById("p1").setAttribute("title",recipe[0].step[1].processingTime);
```

Demo

```js
var text = "13ms";

document.getElementById("p1").setAttribute("title",text);
```

```css
#p1 {
  width:80px;
  height:80px;
  background:#323232;
}
```

```html
<div id="p1"></div>
```

If however you are wanting a fancier one, you can do this with a little javascript and using css [:hover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover), [:after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:after), [attr css function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr), and the [content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content) property.

Give your div (or whatever element) a css class like below:

```
.withTooltip:hover:after {
   content:attr(data-tooltip);
   display:block;
   padding:10px;
   background:#323232;
   border-radius:4px;
   border:#000000;
   color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

- `:hover` will cause the style to applied only when the element is
  hovered over.
- `:after` will create a pseudo-element
- `conent` you can use to set the text that the pseudo-element will display
- `attr` will take the passed attribute name and get the value of that
  attribute

Then use javascript to set the attribute to your saved text (in this case using data-tooltip)

```
document.querySelector("p1").dataset.tooltip = recipe[0].step[1].processingTime;
//or
document.querySelector("p1").setAttribute("data-tooltip",recipe[0].step[1].processingTime);
```

Demo

```js
var someData = ["13ms","100ms","8ms","67ms"];
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".withTooltip");
for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
  elements[i].dataset.tooltip = someData[i];
}
```

```css
.box {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:#86DDFF;
  margin:10px;
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
}

.withTooltip:after {
  content:attr(data-tooltip);
  display:block;
  padding:10px;
  position:absolute;
  right:-40px;
  top:0px;
  background:#323232;
  border-radius:4px;
  border:#000000;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  opacity:0;
  transition:all 0.3s; 
  z-index:100;
  pointer-events:none;
}
.withTooltip:hover:after {
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="box withTooltip"></div>
<div class="box withTooltip"></div>
<div class="box withTooltip"></div>
<div class="box withTooltip"></div>
```

Comment: This should be accepted as an answer because it's really easier !

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery:

```
var a =recipe[0].step[1].processingTime;
$('#p1').mouseenter(function(){
  $(this).html(a)
}).mouseout(function(){
  $(this).html('');
});
```

Comment: but the value does not show in a description box. like what Tooltip do.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried jquery hover method? http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_hover.asp

and if you are using simple javascript try this: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp

Comment: Yes i tried, but all these examples shows how to pop up a value that is in html, like text or image. what I want is to pop up a value which i get from json and stored in a javascript variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is simple:

```
<html>
<script>
    var a = 'the processing time you got from json';

    function displayTitle(e){
        e.title = a;
    }
</script>

<body>
    <table border>
        <tr>
            <td>Recipe 0</td>
            <td onMouseOver='displayTitle(this);'>
                <div id="p1"><div>
                    </td>
    </table>
</body>
```